# Rewrite specific url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a custom php file at the following url

http://www.paradox4a.com/wp-content/themes/whitetheme/custompage.php

I want the user to visit the above link using a virtual url like that

http://www.paradox4a.com/activate/

Is that possible using the .htaccess rewrite_mod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^activate/$ /wp-content/themes/whitetheme/custompage.php [L]
```